# Overwrite ctrl-s and/or command-s to save a question/answer edit

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts

I find myself doing this repeatedly out of habit and wonder if I'm not the only one.

Comment: This isn't necessarily a bad idea, but aren't you used to forms from other websites? No website has you fill out a form and then hit Ctrl+s to submit it

Comment: So switch to a text editor for composing your posts...

Comment: Of course I'm use to forms on other websites, but this site wouldn't be as successful as it is by being just like "other websites".  The main place I think it makes sense is when you're editing content "in-place" like when you edit a post or comment and it's not a separate form, it just turns to a field.  I think it's very intuitive and would resurrect an essentially useless key combo.

Answer (score 1):

While <kbd>⌘S</kbd> isn't a key combo that I hit very often when using my browser, I am strongly opposed to a web site taking over standard keyboard commands. <kbd>⌘L</kbd>, <kbd>⌘Q</kbd>, <kbd>⌘O</kbd>, <kbd>⌘H</kbd>, <kbd>⌘R</kbd>, <kbd>⌘S</kbd> -- these (and really anything (on the Mac) using the command key) should be used to control the browser, not the site.

Comment: I do see your point, and in general I agree with you, but the "save" combo is all but useless in a browser context, Google Docs does this with great convenience in my opinion.